# This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode

Tags: visual-studio-2012

After taking the updates from TFS i start getting this error, Some one suggest me to check the `applicationhost` file in `Documents\IISExpress\config`, I think its fine because i can see

```
<site name="EnviznServicesPlatformGlobal" id="15">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Dot Net\Timothylos\EnviznGlobalWeb\Test\LatestCode\EnviznGlobalWeb\EnviznServicesPlatformGlobal\EnviznServicesPlatformGlobal" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1937:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Here `applicationPool` is showing `Clr4IntegratedAppPool` mode which seems to be correct to me

I want to change the Manage pipeline mode to integrated like this images

[image: property window 2012]

but when i click on properties window i can just just see. 
[image: property window 2012]

My question is how can i change the Managed Pipeline Mode to Integrated in VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an asp.net website you may need to R-click your project and select "Use IIS Express".

If it is a web application you'll need to go into your project's properties pages, select the Web tab then select "Use Local IIS Web server" and check "Use IIS Express".

I had an error (about not using integrated pipeline) which was solved in this way.